# Animating blocks of text and logo as a prelader

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, settimeout, control-flow

Okay, since this is my first question ever asked on stack hope ill be clear as much i can :)

So what i basically want to do here is to animate some text and logo as a preload-er for website. Using Vanilla JavaSccipt only.

What i want to do is to select each DOM that has id block+{number} element and call function that is going to remove class and after that add that removed class again calling back same function, so i have fade in fade out text for each of the "bock's".

This is my HTML Structure:

```
   <section class="txt-wrapper">
            <div id="block1" class="block none">Hello</div>
            <div id="block2" class="block none">Im Maria</div>
            <div id="block3" class="block none">and this is mine</div>
            <div id="block4" class="none">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="WineLogo"></div>
            </div>
       </section>
       <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

And this is JavaScript

```
function ToggleVisibility(el,delay) {
    if (el.classList.contains('none')){
        el.classList.remove('none');
        el.classList.add('display');
        setTimeout(ToggleVisibility(el),delay);
    }
    else {
        el.classList.remove('display');
        el.classList.add('none');
    }
}
var element;
var delay = 2000;
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    element = document.getElementById("block" + String(i));
    ToggleVisibility(element, delay*i);
}
```

update: css

```
.none {
    opacity: 0;
}

.display{
    opacity: 1;
}

.an-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.txt-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    .block {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: ease all 1s;
    }
}
```

i expect for for loop call function for each element and do class change wait for 2 sec than reverse process

Comment: What is the problem? What's not working? Please describe the problem, and what's the current output.

Comment: currently when i type in a console "element" it gives me block4 witch is ok, but in browser i dont see any animations. Script runs instatly, not making timeouts

Comment: What's your CSS?

Comment: its actually scss 
    .none {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .display{
        opacity: 1;
    }

   .an-wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    .txt-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        .block {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width:100%;
            text-align: center;
            transition: ease all 1s;
        }
    }

Comment: for a better overview/readability, plz add the css to your question

Comment: i updated code ty for your comment